# Use all cv::Mat in std::vector and change their value efficiently

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pca

I have a vector of matrices with the same number of columns, i.e. `std::vector<cv::Mat> v` and I want to apply a `cv::PCA` (without dimensionality reduction) using all of them. Finally, I want that the result is applied to original matrices too.

Code speaking, this is the only solution that I came so far:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> v;
//fill v
cv::Mat bigMat;
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
  bigMat.push_back(v[i]);
cv::PCA pca(bigMat, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
  bigMat = pca.project(bigMat);
```

But this doesn't effect `v[i]`. How can I do this efficiently? Notice that I have to use the projected version of `bigMat` later. This is the only solution that came to my mind:

```
cv::PCA pca(bigMat, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);
bigMat.release();
for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
  v[i] = pca.project(v[i]);
  bigMat.push_back(v[i]);
}
```

But this is kinda ugly and I don't know how efficient could be. Is there any better solution (where efficiency is the top priority)?

If you wander, `v[i]` is the set of descriptors of the `i-th` image. If you ask yourself why there is no dimensionality reduction in my PCA, give a look at [this](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00840653v1/document) paper.

Comment: do you want to share the memory between bigMat and the single mats? If yes you can do it the other way around: 1. fill v 2. create bigMat 3. (new): create v2 where the elements of v are filled in again, but as `submatrices` of bigMat. 4. perform all the rest of your code. This will only work if pca doesn't allocate new memory for its results

Comment: How do you fill the initial matrices? If you know in advance all expected sizes, you could define all v[i] being part of a preallocated bigMat, using the [`operator ()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a07413f2e3e63a12185b8b218c24c7270)

Comment: @Antonio As I explained at the end of the question, `v[i]` are the descriptors of an image, which means that I don't know their size in advance (I don't even know `v` size).

Comment: @Micka I'm not sure that I understood your approach, could you please write an answer about it?